# What is the truth value of the statement $\exists ! x \ (x>1)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If the domain consists of all integers, what are the truth values of these statements?

a) $\exists ! x \ (x>1)$

Because the domain consists of all integers then we can loop through all $n$ values of $x$. Besides this wee see that $P(x)$ can only be truth with a domain of positive integers except $1$. So $\exists ! x \ P(x)$ is false.

Am I right?

Comment: What does $\exists !x$ mean?

Comment: It means that there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true, or there exists one and only one $x$.

Comment: Ah ok, but then it suffices to give two examples $x$ that fulfill $P$, to proof it is wrong.

Comment: Yes in principle you could

Comment: It is not true that the existing integer with the property that it is greater than one is unique. So the statement is false.

Answer (score 4):

The statement says that there is a unique integer greater than $1$, i.e. there is only one integer greater than $1$. This is obviously false.